# Submitting ajax on page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I am submitting my AJAX just before the page is loaded and calling it on the same page like this after ajax.

```
<input type="text" class="hidden" id="storeID" value="<?php echo $_GET['store']; ?>">
$(document).ready(function()
{
var store = $("#storeID").val();
$.ajax(
{
  url: '../user-style.php',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {"store":store}
});
});
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../user-style.php" media="screen" />
```

user-style.php

```
if(isset($_POST['store']))
{
$stmtgetstyle = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM store_style_configuration WHERE store_id=?");
$stmtgetstyle->bind_param("i", $_GET['store']);
$stmtgetstyle->execute();
$getstyle = $stmtgetstyle->get_result();
$style = $getstyle->fetch_assoc();
$stmtgetstyle->close();
}
```

But user-style.php isn't getting any data neither any thing is from database is coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to pull the content of the `CSS` and return it. Now you can dynamically put it in a [jQuery Object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../user-style.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {"store":store},
    success: function(data) {
        var $cssStyles = $('<style/>');
        $cssStyles.attr('type', 'text/css');
        $cssStyles.html(data);
        $cssStyles.appendTo($('head'));
    }
});
```

Another method would be to pass it to the current script via the URL parameters with [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../user-style.php?store=store" media="screen" />
```

Or with `jQuery` and `$_GET`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var store = $("#storeID").val();
    var $cssStyles = $('<style/>');
    $cssStyles.attr({ 'type': 'text/css', 'href': '../user-style.php?store=' + store });
    $cssStyles.appendTo($('head'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are posting your data in the ajax call, but are binding to the variable `$_GET['store']`. Just change that to `$_POST['store']` and it should work. This should have also sent out a `notice error` stating there was an `undefined index 'store' in $_GET on line ...`. This is why turning on `error_reporting(E_ALL)` is good when in development.

Edit: actually, on second thought, it might not have thrown an error because when using a variable by reference creates a variable if it doesn't exist and doesn't throw an error. I assume this is the same for undefined array indexes.